# Pyspark not working after installing databricks-connect

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks, databricks-connect

I installed databrick-connect in a conda enviroment, without having pyspark installed (I read that having pyspark would crash with the installation of databricks-connect).
After finishing the configuration of databricks-connect with the cluster,port... info. I tried to run pyspark within the conda enviroment but it does not work:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Name\Anaconda3\envs\conda_env1\Scripts\find_spark_home.py", line 86, in <module>
    print(_find_spark_home())
  File "C:\Users\Name\Anaconda3\envs\conda_env1\Scripts\find_spark_home.py", line 52, in _find_spark_home
    module_home = os.path.dirname(find_spec("pyspark").origin)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'origin'
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the file specified.
The system cannot find the file specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Additional info:
I'm using Windows 10, windows power shell to run my commands.
Java8, Hadoop 3-3.4, databricks-connect==9.1 LTS, python 3.8.

Any ideas what could be the problem ?

Comment: have you able to configure databricks-connect as described in the doc?

Comment: @AlexOtt yes I added the databricks worksplace link, the cluster id, the organisation id, port, key...

Comment: Such a monkey patching is just wrong... Why, Why, Why...?
On versions `databricks-connect==13.3` and `pyspark==3.4` similar problem again and reinstalling pyspark later doesn't help. Development on cluster is way slow, so thumb down Microsoft...

Answer (score 3):

`databricks-connect` during installation (for some uncler to me reason) patches `pyspark` installation adding exception in `pyspark.sql.session.SparkSession.Builder` function `getOrCreate` after the code block searching for the remote spark connection.

Before (docstrings removed):

```py
def getOrCreate(self) -> "SparkSession":
            from pyspark.context import SparkContext
            from pyspark.conf import SparkConf

            opts = dict(self._options)

            with self._lock:
                if "SPARK_REMOTE" in os.environ or "spark.remote" in opts:
                    with SparkContext._lock:
                        from pyspark.sql.connect.session import SparkSession as RemoteSparkSession

                        if (
                            SparkContext._active_spark_context is None
                            and SparkSession._instantiatedSession is None
                        ):
                            url = opts.get("spark.remote", os.environ.get("SPARK_REMOTE"))

                            if url.startswith("local"):
                                os.environ["SPARK_LOCAL_REMOTE"] = "1"
                                RemoteSparkSession._start_connect_server(url, opts)
                                url = "sc://localhost"

                            os.environ["SPARK_REMOTE"] = url
                            opts["spark.remote"] = url
                            return RemoteSparkSession.builder.config(map=opts).getOrCreate()
                        elif "SPARK_LOCAL_REMOTE" in os.environ:
                            url = "sc://localhost"
                            os.environ["SPARK_REMOTE"] = url
                            opts["spark.remote"] = url
                            return RemoteSparkSession.builder.config(map=opts).getOrCreate()
                        else:
                            raise RuntimeError(
                                "Cannot start a remote Spark session because there "
                                "is a regular Spark session already running."
                            )

                session = SparkSession._instantiatedSession
                if session is None or session._sc._jsc is None:
                    sparkConf = SparkConf()
                    for key, value in self._options.items():
                        sparkConf.set(key, value)
                    # This SparkContext may be an existing one.
                    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
                    # Do not update `SparkConf` for existing `SparkContext`, as it's shared
                    # by all sessions.
                    session = SparkSession(sc, options=self._options)
                else:
                    getattr(
                        getattr(session._jvm, "SparkSession$"), "MODULE$"
                    ).applyModifiableSettings(session._jsparkSession, self._options)
                return session
```

and after:

```py
def getOrCreate(self) -> "SparkSession":
            from pyspark.context import SparkContext
            from pyspark.conf import SparkConf

            opts = dict(self._options)

            with self._lock:
                if "SPARK_REMOTE" in os.environ or "spark.remote" in opts:
                    with SparkContext._lock:
                        from pyspark.sql.connect.session import SparkSession as RemoteSparkSession

                        if (
                            SparkContext._active_spark_context is None
                            and SparkSession._instantiatedSession is None
                        ):
                            url = opts.get("spark.remote", os.environ.get("SPARK_REMOTE"))

                            if url.startswith("local"):
                                os.environ["SPARK_LOCAL_REMOTE"] = "1"
                                RemoteSparkSession._start_connect_server(url, opts)
                                url = "sc://localhost"

                            os.environ["SPARK_REMOTE"] = url
                            opts["spark.remote"] = url
                            return RemoteSparkSession.builder.config(map=opts).getOrCreate()
                        elif "SPARK_LOCAL_REMOTE" in os.environ:
                            url = "sc://localhost"
                            os.environ["SPARK_REMOTE"] = url
                            opts["spark.remote"] = url
                            return RemoteSparkSession.builder.config(map=opts).getOrCreate()
                        else:
                            raise RuntimeError(
                                "Cannot start a remote Spark session because there "
                                "is a regular Spark session already running."
                            )

                raise RuntimeError(
                    "Only remote Spark sessions using Databricks Connect are supported. " +
                    "Could not find connection parameters to start a Spark remote session."
                )

                session = SparkSession._instantiatedSession
                if session is None or session._sc._jsc is None:
                    sparkConf = SparkConf()
                    for key, value in self._options.items():
                        sparkConf.set(key, value)
                    # This SparkContext may be an existing one.
                    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
                    # Do not update `SparkConf` for existing `SparkContext`, as it's shared
                    # by all sessions.
                    session = SparkSession(sc, options=self._options)
                else:
                    getattr(
                        getattr(session._jvm, "SparkSession$"), "MODULE$"
                    ).applyModifiableSettings(session._jsparkSession, self._options)
                return session
```

It prevents creation of local Spark session altogether. But you can simply reinstall `pyspark` in this case (or better install `databricks-connect` first and then `pyspark` to avoid this patching.

Comment: That this is "allowed" is super shady to me.  Not sure how to do this automatically in a pipeline build step to ensure that pyspark isn't touched by databricks. It seems super bad practice

Answer (score 0):

Please set SPARK_HOME. get SPARK_HOME by executing databricks-connect get-spark-home

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).